# Is this spam? I can't read it

Tags: discussion, bug

[image]

Is this some kind of glitch, or an actual message?
Can't read it [can't even pronounce cyrillic let alone translate it], can't copy/paste it as the entire message is a link in that drop menu.

Link itself just goes to http://ru.stackoverflow.com not any specific message page.

I'm not signed up to StackOverflow itself, English or Russian so can't really post it to their Meta.

Answer (score 1):

It's an automated Stack Exchange message asking you to help with Stack Overflow in Russian. These messages are usually sent for events such as a moderator election being held on a site that you have an account on. Receiving a message for a site you don't have an account on seems like a bug, unless this is a special message I'm not aware of.

I seem to recall receiving a similar message about a different site a very long time ago, but perhaps I'm misremembering. Unfortunately these kinds of messages don't appear in the inbox API endpoint, so I can't search my inbox history.

By the way, running the message [through Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/#ru/en/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%0AStack%20Overflow%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8!) gives me the following:

> Message
>   Stack Overflow in Russian needs your help!

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't even get as far as Google Trans, as I've no way to generate cyrillic [other than adding a Russian keyboard, then visually scanning the Keyboard Viewer, hoping to find a pictorial match]  :)